# how to feed string to pyparsing line by line?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I encounter this question when I want to parse a file with large size using pyparsing. I have already created the pyparsing grammar for the whole file. But I am not sure how to feed the string to the parser line by line by reading this big file. Currently I am using the the method like:

```
pyparsingGrammer = some pyparsing grammar I created
PyparsingGrammar.parseString(open(filename).read())
```

Except the memory usage for the big `read()`, another motivation for me to go for line feeding is to extend my parser to a realtime case where info is feeded to the parser one line followed by another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do :

```
with open(filename) as f:
     for line in f:
         PyparsingGrammar.parseString(line)
```

using the keyword `with` automatically closes the file once you are done, and gives you a handle to work with.

```
for x in something:
    do_something
```

is a standard way of going over iterables (stuff which can be iterated, e.g: `list, tuple, dictionary` in Python.

I forgot to mention, but I guess you figured it:
when you open a file in Python with `with open(filename) as f` you are getting a `list` where each line in the list is an item. That is why you are able to treat `f` as an iterator.

Comment: cool,it works and pyparsing does complain. Actually I notice the way that python do the basic file I/O. But still wondering why pyparsing can accept the way that the parsing data are feeded to it line by line. I thought I need to give it everything that matches the grammar previously defined. But it turns out differently.

Comment: @user1705411, it `does` or `does not`? what is the error? if it works, you should accept the answer.